# create array with iterative assignment

Tags: ruby, language-lawyer

Would like to exploit the following behaviour in Ruby

```
ary = Array.new(5) { |i|
   [i, j=2*i, k=j+1]
}

p ary #> [[0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [3, 6, 7], [4, 8, 9]]
```

It works for my purposes, but I couldn't find in the language definition whether this is legal Ruby.  Is it? Or is it likely to break in the future?

[Edit] A smaller working example raising the same issue is

```
i = 1
ary = [i, j=2*i, k=j+1]

p ary #> [1, 2, 3]
```

But of course this example only has theoretical relevance contrary to the first, which does have practical relevance.

Comment: What does the documentation for the Ruby `Array` class say about the `new` method?

Comment: Ruby returns value of last evaluated statement. What makes you think it's not legal?

Comment: @lurker: it's the inner array creation that the Ruby array spec seems unclear about.

Comment: @bravemaster: because specs seem inconclusive in this respect.

Comment: Not a problem. More generally, `[i, j=m1(i), m2(i,j)]` is fine for any methods `m1` and `m2`. That wouldn't be in the doc for `Array::new` because it is fundamental Ruby behavior (that is common to other languages).

Comment: The [Array#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new) constructor with a block uses the block's return values to determine the contents of the array. Since an array can contain anything, there's no reason why this _wouldnt_ work. You can't expect to have specs / documentation covering every singe form of array you can build. And by the way, the `j=` and `k=` in the block are pointless, just return the values directly without assigning them to these temporary variables

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing there. The temporary variables are _not_ pointless.

Comment: @lurker: the relevant question is about the guarantees for the order of evaluation of array literal elements, which would not be documented in the API docs, it is part of the language specification. And it is by no means obvious. I have read the ISO Ruby Language Specification, and still couldn't say off the top of my head whether there are any guarantees or not.

Comment: @bravemaster: the relevant question is about the guarantees for the order of evaluation of array literal elements. And it is by no means obvious. I have read the ISO Ruby Language Specification, and still couldn't say off the top of my head whether there are any guarantees or not.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: the question is, where is this guaranteed? I can't remember off the top of my head having seen it in the ISO Ruby Language Specification, for example. And I can imagine legitimate reasons for not wanting to make a guarantee such as automated vectorization. (Not that I believe the Ruby core team would use that reasoning.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag ah yes, I see what you mean. It's not the definition of the `new` block evaluation itself that's unclear, but perhaps the evaluation of the sub-array elements. This question has nothing to do with `Array#new` at all, but is about the evaluation of the `[i, j=2*i, k=j+1]` expression itself.

Comment: @lurker: I wouldn't be surprised if left-to-right is guaranteed, but I can't say that it is without diving into the specs. I usually prefer not to write code that requires having the spec printed out on your desk, therefore I don't know such things by heart.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I was looking at the details given for `::[]` in the `Array` documentation. It looks like it's equivalent to the question of whether a method call would evaluate it's arguments in order. So does `foo(a, b, c)` evaluate `a`, then `b`, then `c` before calling `foo`?

Comment: if `[i, j=2*i, k=j+1]` is specifically what you're asking about in your question, you should be more explicit. It's not obvious from reading the question

Comment: @lurker: An array literal is not a message send, though. I believe argument binding in message send argument lists is implicitly guaranteed to be left-to-right, sind there is an assertion somewhere buried deep within `ruby/spec` that uses values of parameter bindings to the left as default argument values for optional positional parameters to the right, but I would have to dig that up, too.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I like the answer but I don't get it.  I don't get the "it is fundamental Ruby behaviour".

Comment: @maxpleaner: I've edited the question to an almost MWE.

Comment: Your new example is not theoretical at all. It's a very practical example that can occur in programming and is the essence of your question.

Comment: Koert and @Jörg, I know, merely from experience, that Ruby evaluates method arguments left-to-right. `[i=0,i+1] #=> [0,1]`, but `[i+1,i] #=> NameError (undefined local variable or method 'i' for main:Object)`. Is this a specification of the language? I don't know, but I expect that legions of Ruby coders have over many years written millions of lines of code that depend on arguments being evaluated left-to-right. One can debate whether that is good programming practice, but we can agree that a new version of Ruby that does not evaluate arguments left-to-right would cause havoc...

Comment: ...The same issue may occur if, for argument-less methods `m1` and `m2` when `[m1, m2]` evaluated. If `m1` is evaluated first we obtain `m1 #=> v1` and then `m2 #=> v2`, but if `m2` were evaluated first `m2` and `m1` may return values different than `v2` and `v1`. It might be advantageous to have parallel processing of method arguments baked into the language (as opposed to creating threads). That would require new coding norms, however, so it would effectively be a new language. Putting that aside, if arguments are evaluated sequentially, I see no reason the Ruby monks would deviate from...

Comment: ...the current actual or *de facto* specification that they are evaluated left-to-right, and if it is merely *de facto* I think there's a good argument to make it a formal specification.